# storing and restoring a vhd backup on azure?

Tags: azure, ubuntu, backup, vhd

So I plan to spurn up a VM (first time) to run an application build process. It needs a computer with a heavy configuration. I plan to keep it alive until the build process is over, and, I've manually tested stuff.

Then I'd want to decommission it. But prior to that I want an image backup. Assuming here that *that* is what I want: an image backup (vhd). Since I will need those same programs + files (on disk) to be available the next time I *restore* the VM.

Hence while obtaining the vhd where can I store it, so that the next time I want to start up a vm with the same image, it would be fairly quick?

Downloading it to my local machine, is not a good option, since I fear the  vhd file size will be huge, and I might waste considerable bandwidth downloading/uploading it.

The instance I plan to use will be an ubuntu server with 8 cores and 32 gb ram.

Comment: Do you know if the machine you have deployed is a Resource Manager VM or a VM (Classic) as it changes how imaging works a little

Answer (score 0):

You can click the "disks" and attach it as Data Disks. When you delete the old VM, make sure you didn't selete the VHD to also delete the VHD, once this VHD is no longer being used by any other VM, you can attach it as Dada Disks.

Hope this will help.